# How can I override XMLHttpRequest in my Android WebView subclass so that scripts in head will use my overridden XHR?

Tags: android, webview, xmlhttprequest

I am working on what amounts to a custom android web browser and need to work around a bug in XHR.
I'd like to use a javascript XHR wrapper that fixes the bug (I already have the fix).

How can I force this to be loaded on every page load before anything else is loaded, including scripts in the head?

Note that arbitrary web content which I do not control will be loaded into my webview, so I can't do anything like load my script from the html page.  I need to do something like intercept the first script request in head and synchronously inject my script.  I'm not sure if this exact approach is possible - just trying to provide an example of the sort of approach that would satisfy my requirements.

I'm open to a completely different approach - I just know how to fix it via a javascript wrapper.

The details of the bug that I need to fix are not important, but just in case anyone is curious, successful XMLHttpRequests for non-android_asset file urls leave status set to 0 and statusText to "". Since some frameworks that use XHR treat status!=200 and/or statusText!="OK" as an error, I need to override the default behavior and return status=200 and statusText="OK" for successful XMLHttpRequests for non-android_asset file urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since someone recently upvoted this and no one else offered any input, I'll share what I ended up doing to address the problem, even though it does not really address my original question.

In my case, I am only loading local (that is, dynamic files that are copied locally prior to being loaded into the webview) html files which I have access to via the filesystem prior to loading them into the webview.  Therefore, I have an opportunity to modify the file prior to loading them.  Since I could not find a better approach, I simply insert a script tag as first child of head in order to ensure that XHR override happens before anything else.

Feel free to comment if you want more details - I will do my best to answer!